# VScode: Disable syntax highlighting for a range of lines

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, assembly, syntax-highlighting, sdcc

I'm using SDCC's inline assembly syntax for my project:

```
void delay_ms(uint16_t ms) {
    _ms = ms;
    __asm
        ldw y, __ms         ; Load ms counter into y register: 2 cycles
    0000$:
        ldw x, _CYCLES_PER_MS   ; Load tick counter into x register: 2 cycles
    0001$:              
        decw x          ; Decrease tick counter: 1 cycle 
        jrne 0001$      ; Check if 1ms passed: 2 cycles (except for x == 0 where it's just 1 cycle)
                
        decw y          ; Decrease ms counter: 1 cycle
        jrne 0000$      ; Check if provided time has passed: 2 cycles (except for y == 0 where it's just 1 cycle)
    __endasm;
}
```

Unfortunately VScode's language syntax highlighting still interprets the inline assembly code as C code which is quite annoying:

[image]

Is it possible to completely disable syntax highlighting for a range of lines in your file?

Comment: if you modify the C TextMate grammar you can inject this section as Assembler and get that syntax highlighting, just like JavaScript inside HTML files

Comment: related google search query: "`github vscode cpptools issues "__asm" highlight`". standard syntax for asm is support I think.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default setting for that, and as far as I can see, no extension that supports it.

It is possible to treat the entire file as an asm source file. This will still support some very basic C highlighting. To do this, look for *asm-collection* mode in **Select Language Mode** menu.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, highlighting can be disabled entirely for the file, via the same menu, or, through **settings.json** in case it needs to be applied to multiple files.

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.c": "plaintext",
},
```